# How to call two functions in one onClick handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking to pass another function to a child component that is already being passed `onClick` props to be able to disable it when it is clicked on. I'm aware I should extract the current onClick action into a separate function, and implement the disabling action there as well, however I am having a problem with `this.props.onClick` (func PropType) executing correctly when I extract it. Is there a way to go about it without using a separate function or I am just calling `this.props.onClick` improperly when I extract it?

Below is the current code I am working with (no disable actions implemented)

```
render() {
    const b = block('btn').mix('btn').mix('action-button');

    return (
      <button
        onClick={this.props.onClick}
        className={b(this.props.className)}
        title={this.props.title}
      >
        {this.props.buttonText}
      </button>
    );
    }
```

Comment: cant you just call the second function in your click event handler?

Comment: Silly question I guess - but how would I do that?

Comment: Not sure, provide some code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question exactly but would it help to create a separate method on your class of

```
    handleClick () {
       this.props.onClick()
       otherOnClickFunc()
    }
```

and pass your handler `this.click()` instead of `this.props.onClick()` ?

Comment: (make sure to add `this.click = this.click.bind(this)` to your constructor)